# Handling Response from Python POST Request

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, python-requests

New to Python here so bear with me:

I'm using the awesome Requests module to make a POST request to Facebook Graph API. Here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests 


access_token = '9DYWNDXKPsTUkW1TcFZA5E1gUsIhliA0wMc0YZAmcu2Qtd8MtJVW50Y2ZBpnjkw8FH8d5LTmm7AuJ35pQo5'
fburl = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/56914066/videos?access_token='+str(access_token)
payload = {'upload_phase': 'start', 'file_size': '6999244'}
flag = requests.post(fburl, data=payload).text
print flag
```

I'm running this Python script locally on my Mac OSX machine, using Python 2.7, from Terminal. The response I get from the Facebook API, which is printed out in Terminal:

```
{"video_id":"635631120558","start_offset":"0","end_offset":"1048576","upload_session_id":"6356311891"}
```

Now, I assuming that:

1. This response is a dictionary, correct? And it's a JSON response?
2. I'm also assuming that that means the variable "flag" is a JSON object?

My big question: Should I be able to iterate through "flag" as a dictionary or JSON object?

Just a  bit confused on what's being returned in Terminal and how I can deal with the "flag" variable in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is calling the `text` method of the `requests` object, and so the (*JSON*) response is getting converted into a string, which you are then printing out. So you would not be able to iterate over that.

However, if you don't call `text`, the resulting object should be a *JSON* object (based on a quick glance at the *Facebook Graph API* doc) that you can iterate over using the built-in [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). See the *Decoding JSON* section.

e.g. if you `import json` at the top of your code, you could then do something like this:

```
flagJson = requests.post(fburl, data=payload)
flagDict = json.loads(flagJson)
```

And then you can iterate over `flagDict` as you would any other `dict`.

**Edit in response to follow-up comment from OP:**

`json.loads(flagJson)` *decodes* the *JSON* into a *Python* `dict` which can then be used as any other `dict` would. It all depends on what you want to do with it. Most likely, if you want to manipulate it in any way, you'll want to *decode* it, as then you can iterate over it, change values, write it out in another format, or *encode* it back into *JSON* with any changes you've made to it.

Comment: Thank you for that very succinct break down, got it figured out now!

Comment: Just had a question after playing around with this: if we leave off .text in our POST request, thus allowing Facebook's server response to remain a JSON object, do I have to decode the JSON object response from their server using json.loads(flag)? What exactly does that do?

Comment: Just for the record:  you don't even need to manually call `json.loads()`- `request.post(fburl, data=payload).json()` will take care of it.